# Windows forms, creating dynamic scroll-able panel

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, controls

I have a custom control pictured below on the left. I would like to create another custom control that can dynamically add more or less of these controls to itself programmatically, and allow the user to scroll through them to see the "information" in each edit box. I want to make it generic enough that if I have to show information for x number of things, I could just programmatically "add" more of these controls to the custom control and scroll through them.

[image]

I would imagine that I should start with a `Panel` control (Would this take care of scroll bars)?

How could I add/remove/keep track of the edit controls I'd like to display?

Comment: I'd start with `TableLayoutPanel` which is better for holding dynamic content. Your custom control should have some kind of `ItemsToShowCount` property.

Comment: What are you inner controls? Are them another UserControl, or are you drawing them manually?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn The inner like the one pictured on the left. He wants a scrollable container for them.

Comment: I guess my biggest question is, how would I add and remove them from the panel while keeping them from overlapping? ie how could I add one to the end of the list and "draw" it properly. Would I have to keep track of the coordinates of the end of the list manually and add each one there?

Comment: Are you drawing them manually? Posting some code will help.

Comment: No, I have made them with the MicroVisualStudio forms/controls designer

Comment: @user1596244 Well, then my answer will apply. Tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Panel` control (as you guessed) and set its [`AutoScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx) property to `true` (this takes care of scroll bars).

If your inner controls are some other `UserControl` objects, keep a list of them in your outer UserControl, and add them dynamically at the bottom of the stack:

```
var innerControl = new MyInnerUserControl();
innerControl.Top = _innerControls[_innerControls.Count-1].Bottom + 1;
_innerControls.Add(innerControl);
```

But if you are drawing your content manually, you should set the [`AutoScrollMinSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollminsize.aspx) property of the panel to the total size of your inner content.